# Quiz in Windows Forms. Check if button is right answer or not

Tags: c#, button, click

I'm doing a "Who wants to be a millionaire"-like game and I'm stuck at how to check if the answer is the right answer or not.

I've made a `struct` that I can use to create some questions which looks like this:

```
struct Question
{
    public string question, ansA, ansB, ansC, ansD;
    public int correctAnswer;
}
```

Then I make questions like this:

```
Question ett = new Question();    
ett.question = "Who is the richest?";
ett.ansA = "XXXX";
ett.ansB = "god";
ett.ansC = "vit";
ett.ansD = "röd";
ett.correctAnswer = 1;
```

And after that I put them in a list and retrieve a random question from there. The question in a label and the answers in four different buttons.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int number = rnd.Next(0, NumberOfquestions+1);
var question = QuestionList[number];

lblquestion.Text = question.question;
button1.Text = question.ansA;
button2.Text = question.ansB;
button3.Text = question.ansC;
button4.Text = question.ansD;
```

The variable names aren't 100% correct because I've changed them for you to understand them since I have the variables in my language.

I'm stuck on how to check if the button clicked is right or not, and I have some thoughts about it but I'm unsure if that will work or if there are any better ways to do it.

One thing I thought was to make a method that check if its right, if the button return a value between 1-4 and check it against my `int correctAnswer` in the `struct`.

```
public int button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   return 1; 
}
```

Another thing I thought about was if I could make a method including all of the right answers in the game and search through if that match the text on my button?
Maybe not the best method to use.

```
namespace quiz
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            programmet();
        }

        public void btnNewGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void BtnAvsluta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Dispose();
            this.Close();
        }

        public void programmet()
        {
            Question ett = new Question();
            ett.fråga = "who is richest ?";
            ett.svarA = "XXXX";
            ett.svarB = "god";
            ett.svarC = "vit";
            ett.svarD = "röd";
            ett.rättsvar = 1;



            var QuestionList = new List<Question>();
            QuestionList.Add(ett);
            QuestionList.Add(tre);
            QuestionList.Add(fyra);
            QuestionList.Add(fem);

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int number = rnd.Next(0, numberOfQuestions -1);
            var currentQuestion = QuestionList[number];

            lblFråga.Text = currentQuestion.fråga;
            button1.Text = currentQuestion.svarA;
            button2.Text = currentQuestion.svarB;
            button3.Text = currentQuestion.svarC;
            button4.Text = currentQuestion.svarD;
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           /// here I want to use CurrentQuestion.question etc. 
           /// to do the "if(currentquestion.ansA == 1)"
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: May be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

Define a variable to store the current question (`currentQuestion`) that is accessible from the Click event handler of each button and from the method in which you select the question.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
   if (currentQuestion.correctAnswer == 1)
      CorrectAnswer();
   else
      WrongAnswer();
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
   // same for button2 ...
}
```

Comment: that was what i thought about from the beginning and i've done pretty much that. But i can't get that "currentQuestion.correctAnser" to be accessible in my button action.

Comment: Can you post your complete code or explain why it doesn't work for you?

Comment: You could declare `private Question currentQuestion;` instead of `var currentQuestion` outside the `programmet` method. Then it's accessible from each method inside the class `Form1`

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the `Tag`s of your answer buttons, so `button1.Tag = 1`, `button2.Tag = 2` etc. Then, for all your answer buttons, set their `Click` event to the **same** method, e.g.

```
void Answer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In the method body, you can then access the `Tag` of the clicked button using...

```
int selectedAnswer = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;
```

To access your current question, make a private property or field in your `Form1` class:

```
private Question CurrentQuestion;
```

and in your `programmet()` method, assign to it like this:

```
this.CurrentQuestion = QuestionList[number];
```

...so you can use

```
if (CurrentQuestion.correctAnswer == selectedAnswer) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is when you're loading the answers onto the form set the appropriate button's tag to true and the rest false.  Now in the common click event handler check the tag value of sender cast to a button and you have whether the answer is right

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create two methods called CorrectAnswer() and IncorrectAnswer() and call the appropriate one from each button click. like so.

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
//if answer is correct
CorrectAnswer();

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
//if answer is incorrect
IncorrectAnswer();
```

hope this helps